# SQL command works in interactive mode but no in bash script in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, linux, bash, oracle, sqlplus

command that works in in sqlplus

```
INSERT INTO DATA_SM_METRIC(UNIQUE_ID,METRIC_REVIEW_CRITERION_DESC,METRICS_REVIEW_CRITERION_VALUE,ENTITY_TYPE,REVIEWCRITERIATYPE,CREATETIME)
SELECT UNIQUE_ID,METRIC_REVIEW_CRITERION_DESC,METRICS_REVIEW_CRITERION_VALUE,ENTITY_TYPE,REVIEWCRITERIATYPE,CREATETIME FROM DATA_SM_METRIC_STG;
```

When insert into the shell script it just pauses and above never gets executed. The ...stg table is populated and all records are transferred into the other table. Why is it not being populated into the other table from the staging table?

Script:

```
DATAFILE=$1

SQLPATH=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.2/db_1/bin

SQLPLUS=$SQLPATH/sqlplus

SQLLOADER=$SQLPATH/sqlldr


echo "Start loading file into staging table ->sqlldr $DATAFILE"

$SQLLOADER userid=system/oracle@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl12c 
control=./$DATAFILE.ctl data=./$DATAFILE log=./$DATAFILE.log  
bad=./$DATAFILE.bad skip=1 errors=100
echo $?


echo "start inserting records......"
rec=`$SQLPLUS -S  system/oracle@127.0.0.1:1521/orcl12c  <<EOF | sed 1,3d        
INSERT INTO CIBC_DATA_SM_METRIC(UNIQUE_ID,METRIC_REVIEW_CRITERION_DESC,METRICS_REVIEW_CRITERION_VALUE,ENTITY_TYPE,REVIEWCRITERIATYPE,CREATETIME)
SELECT UNIQUE_ID,METRIC_REVIEW_CRITERION_DESC,METRICS_REVIEW_CRITERION_VALUE,ENTITY_TYPE,REVIEWCRITERIATYPE,CREATETIME FROM CIBC_DATA_SM_METRIC_STG; 
exit
EOF`
```

Comment: Did you rollback (or commit, but probably not) in the SQL\*Plus session before running the script version?

Comment: @AlexPoole what do you mean to commit before running the script?

Comment: Not related to your issue, but you really shouldn't be connecting as `system` or creating your own objects in that schema (or any other built-in schema).

Comment: I mean, you said you ran the insert statement in SQL\*Plus. Is that session still active, or have you exited from the `SQL>` prompt? If it is still active did you commit or rollback after performing the insert? The `unique_id` column implies there is a unique or primary key, so your shell-based insert may just be blocked waiting for an uncommited change in another session.

Comment: @AlexPoole Yes I did not close the other session and did not commit it. Just did it and now it works. Thanks :)